# Nginx Reverse proxy with docker compose throwing 502 gateway error

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am working on a poc where i have list of microservices and i want to expose them using nginx reverse proxy. However any try to use proxy, It is throwing **502 gate way** response. Could anyone please suggest what i am missing in this config?

services being used:

1. nginx reverse proxy
2. node app (A simple node js/ express app which returns hello world)

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
    services:
        nginx-ms:
          image: nginx
          container_name: nginx-ms
          ports:
            - 80:80
          networks:
            - backend-services
          volumes:
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

        cart-ms:
          image: "node:12.9.0"
          container_name: cart-ms
          user: "node"
          working_dir: /home/node/app
          volumes:
            - ./node:/home/node/app
          ports:
            - 3000:3000
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - |
              npm start
          networks:
            - backend-services
    volumes:
      mongodb:
      postgres_data:
      keycloak:
    networks:
      backend-services:
      frontend-services:
```

nginx.conf

```
    worker_processes auto;
    
    events {
      worker_connections 8000;
      multi_accept on;
      use epoll;
    }
    
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
    
    http {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      server_tokens off;
      include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=1s;
    
      charset_types text/xml text/plain text/vnd.wap.wml application/x-javascript application/rss+xml text/css application/javascript application/json;
    
      keepalive_timeout 20;
      sendfile        on;
      include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    
    }
```

default.conf

```
proxy_cache_path cache/  keys_zone=auth_cache:10m;
proxy_cache_path tenant_cache/  keys_zone=tenant_cache:10m;
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}
# upstream cart {
#     server 127.0.0.1:3000;
# }
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name  localhost;
    
    location /cart {
            proxy_pass http://cart-ms:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    
    error_page  404  /404.html;
    location /404.html {
        return 404 null;
    }
}
```

Whenever i try with http://localhost/cart it gives **502 Bad Gateway** response.
How to debug this issue?

I have tried most of the solution available in stack overflow but couldnt find a valid solution in my case.

you can check the files [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-2yhexg?file=nginx%2Fdefault.conf,docker-compose.yaml,node%2Fapp.js,nginx%2Fnginx.conf)

Comment: I have found the solution after hard read . Solution which worked for me is binding host docker to container . Adding below line as part of volume section of docker-compose yaml worked for me 
volumes: 
- /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro